# Least Squares with Singular $AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, least-squares

Given the following system, find all least squares solutions:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\2 & 3 & 4\\3 & 4 & 5\end{bmatrix}  \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$
However, after trying to minimize residuals with:
$\vec{x} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$
I found that $det(AA^T)$ is singular... I think this means that their exist infinitely many least squares solutions to the system, but I don't know how to go about describing them all. I am relatively new to linear algebra (Uni level into class at the moment) so any help/explanation would be great!

Comment: Indeed, if $A$ is singular, then you cannot calculate the inverse of $A^TA$. In the case of a singular $A$, one needs to replace the term $(A^T A)^{-1}A$ by the Moore-Penrose-Pseudoinverse $A^+$ of $A$.

Comment: Use that fact that $\ker  A^T A = \ker A = \operatorname{sp} \{ (1,-2,1)^T \} $.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure how this fits in to the problem at hand... can you explain a bit further please?

Comment: You are looking for all $x$ that solve $A^TA x = A^Tb$. If you find any solution $x_0$ then $x_0+n$ is also a solution for any $n \in \ker A^TA = \ker A$. A solution to $A^TA x = A^Tb$ must exist and you can find a solution any way you wish, such as row reduction. So, you need to characterise $\ker A$. I have given one element above, you can show that $A$ has rank 2 (look at the range, for example).

Comment: @copper.hat great! ok I fully understand the procedure you laid out, but am still slightly unsure as to _exactly_ why we can conclude that $x_0 + n$ is a solution. Specifically, why do we care about n being in the kernel? Is it because the determinant of $A^TA$ is 0, so we are looking for all vectors that send $A^TA$ to 0? Additionally, why isn't the solution $x_0 + \lambda n$ where lambda is a real number, as the kernel is closed under scalar multiplication as well as addition?

Comment: If $A n = 0$ then $A (x_0+n) = A x_0 + A n = A x_0$. Hence if $x_0$ solves $A^TA x_0 = A^T b$ then so does $x_0+n$. The space $\ker A$ is a subspace, so it includes the line through $n$, but it is a matter of preference how you write it.

Comment: @copper.hat that makes a lot of sense! Thank you. If you post your original comment in the answer section, I will endorse it as the correct answer.

Comment: If $x_1,x_1$ are two solutions you must have $A^T A (x_1-x_0) = 0$ and so $x_1-x_0 \in \ker A^TA$. You can show $\ker A^TA = \ker A$. This is why we care about $\ker A$.

Comment: No worries, glad to help!

Comment: I think it is said in the comments that a solution to $A^TAx=A^Tb$ must exist, but in the example given in the original question, if $A^TA$ is singular, no solution would exist.

Answer (score 4):

The "least squares approximation" is $\hat x$ such that $\|A\hat x -b\|$ is minimized.

Consider overdetermined systems:

If $A^TA$ is invertible, $\hat x =(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ is the only $\hat x$ that minimizes $\|A\hat x -b\|$.

If $A^TA$ is singular, there are infinitely many approximations that minimize $\|A\hat x -b\|$. They are given by $\hat x=A^+b+(I-A^+A)w$ for any vector w, where $A^+$ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$.

When $A^TA$ is invertible, only one approximation exists that minimizes $\|A\hat x -b\|$.  But when $A^TA$ is singular, many approximations exist that minimize $\|A\hat x -b\|$, and one of these has minimal $\|\hat x\|$.  This is $\hat x=A^+b$.

Note that $\hat x=A^+b$ is also a best approximation when $A^TA$ is invertible, as in this case $A^+=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.  And also in this case $(I-A^+A)=0$, which is why there is only one approximation that minimizes $\|A\hat x -b\|$.

Consider square systems:

If A is invertible, $\hat x=A^{-1}b$ is the exact solution to $Ax=b$, and therefore minimizes $\|A\hat x -b\|$ to be $0$.

If $A$ is singular (thus $A^TA$ is also singular), and the equation $\hat x=A^+b+(I-A^+A)w$ minimizes $\|A\hat x -b\|$, and one of these has minimal $\|\hat x\|$.  This is $\hat x=A^+b$.

Consider underdetermined systems:

If $A$ is full rank, $x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$ is an exact solution where $Ax =b$ and it also has minimal $\|x\|$.

If $A$ is not full rank, $\hat x=A^+b$ is a solution with minimal $\|A\hat x -b\|$ and minimal $\| \hat x \|$ and for any vector w, $\hat x = A^+b+(I-A^+A)w$ is a least squares solution that may not have minimal $\| \hat x\|$.

Also if $A$ is full rank, $A^+=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$.